# menu dropdown bootstrap não abre!

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, dropdown

Pagina com bootstrap

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
         <img src="img/Pictures-icon.png" width="70px">
    </a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#conheça-nos">conheça-nos</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#atendimento">atendimento</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">parceiros</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Ação</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Outra ação</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Algo mais aqui</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Desativado</a>
              </li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
 </nav>
```

Comment: Colocar o código completo! Dessa forma esta difícil contribuir

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pagina com bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

Comment: comentei aqui o resto do meu codigo pois na edição a parte do <head> n estava aparecendo

Comment: Algumas funções do Bootstrap só funcionam com jQuery, como o collapse, por exemplo.

Comment: ent eu tenho que baixar o jquey certo?

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um exemplo simples, contudo atente para as bibliotecas utilizadas.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdowns</h2>                                         
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: n estou usando o js, só o css/bootstrap

Comment: é importante utilizar!

Comment: tenho que utilizar o jquery o js juntos, ou um dos dois ja funciona?

Comment: sim, o javascript é o responsavel pelo movimento. Html é uma strutura, Css o a exibição e o javascritp é a ação

Comment: <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: assim ja funciona?

Comment: se vc inseriu bootstrap.min.js na pasta raiz do sites sim. Atente para os locais onde vc inserios *.js